# Error tweeting a certain sentence

Tags: twitter

On the Twitter web interface, I'm trying to tweet - for several weeks - this exact sentence:

```
D. B. Cooper https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper
```

But this is totally impossible: I always get an internal server error message for an unknown reason. This is what I get in Firebug:

[image]

I poked the Twitter support, but no response since weeks. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried http instead of https?

Comment: The Twitter web app doesn't allow non-secure HTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383095/why-does-twitter-disallow-dots-in-public-web-addresses) posted around the same time on Stack Overflow, Twitter would not allow for *additional* dots in URLs to be included in a post. Not from a technical point of view, but by the choice of Twitter. (This is evidenced by URLs containing additional dots working in Facebook around the same time.)

However since then, Twitter appears to have allowed this to work:

[image: Twitter_URL]

Comment: Yup it seems I can finally tweet this sentence now. Thanks for the precision!